# Mathematical computer desk

Tags: ho.history-overview, soft-question, na.numerical-analysis

D. Gibb, from the Mathematical Laboratory, University of Edinburgh,
describes a **Computer Desk** in his book **A course in interpolation and numerical integration for the
mathematical laboratory**, G. Bell & Sons, Ltd., **1915**, available [here](http://archive.org/stream/courseininterpol00gibbuoft#page/n13/mode/2up):

*Where computation is performed to any considerable extent, computer's desk will be found useful. Those used in the mathematical laboratory of the University of Edinburgh are 3' 0" wide, 1'9" from front to back, and 2'6  1/2" high. They contain a locker, in wich computing paper can be kept without being folded, and a cupboard for books, papers, drawing-board, arithmometer, or instruments. Each desk is supplied with a copy of Barlow's tables (which gives the square, square root, cube, cube root and the reciprocal of all numbers up to 10,000), a copy of Creller's multiplication table (which gives at sight the product of any two numbers each less than 1000), and
tables giving the values of the trigonometric functions and logarithms*

Question: Are there any available picture of this "computer desk" ?

> > I think that this may be the first recorded description of an workplace for numerical analysts...

Comment: I don"t know.  However, the Deutsches Museen in Munich has a large display devoted to computing machinery from antiquity to mere "ancient history" (I think they have a Macintosh as an exhibit).  If anyone has a picture on file, I bet they do or know about it.
Gerhard "Ich Wuensche Nach Muenchen Gehen" Paseman, 2012.08.17

Comment: "I think that this may be the first recorded description of an workplace for numerical analysts..." I cannot prove this wrong but it seems highly unlikely to me in view of the fact that for centuries (not to say millenia) before this task was already carried out. I have a vague recollection of reading Gauss (I think, but definitely that period of time), while not describing the persons working desk, complaining on poor working habits of his (human) computer. 

Comment: What is an arithmometer?

Comment: @Igor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmometer


Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will interpret this question a bit freely:

There is a long history of humans performing computational tasks (not mathematics) as a profession, and the technical tools and tables they had.

The [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/) has among many other things some nice pictures of mechannical devices used to that end online, see in particular http://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/calculators/1

The Barlow's tables mentioned in the text can be found in digital form here http://archive.org/details/barlowstablesofs00barlrich  And, the LOCOMAT project collects together numerous digitized version of historical math tables and related info, see in particular http://locomat.loria.fr/locomat/digital-tables.html where also a link Crelle's tables (also mentioned) is to be found (year is 1820, to make it easier to find).

There is also a recent book [When Computers Were Human](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7999.html) by D.A. Grier on the people doing this and with the same title one can find a video taped talk online (on youtube for instance). 
[Disclaimer: I did not watch the video and have no detailed knwoledge on the content of the book, but it clearly seems relevant.]

ps: the justification for interpreting this so freely is that I think the question for some desks at the Univerity of Edinburgh is 'too localized' as long as there is no clear evidence they are in any sense special or of historical significance.

Comment: @quid: Thank you for your answer and links. The desks at University of Edinburgh has historical significance because *I think that this may be the first recorded description of a desk for numerical analysts...* ;)

Comment: @PaPiro: You are welcome. Well, as I said I am not so convinced of this 'first', but let us not quarel on this detail :) 

Answer (score 7):

A little googling led to http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Extras/EMS_1913_Colloquium.html which quotes at length a report that appeared in *The Mathematical Gazette* in 1913, including the following:

> ...Professor Whittaker held his *séances*
>   in the large basement hall, which has
>   recently been fitted up as a
>   mathematical laboratory. This, indeed,
>   was the first occasion on which it had
>   been used. Each student was provided
>   with a specially designed desk, with a
>   convenient book-rest fixed to the
>   back, and with drawers and shelves for
>   storing note-books, scribbling paper,
>   graph paper, and books to aid
>   calculation, such as Barlow's *Tables*
>   and Crelle's *Rechentafeln*. At these
>   desks learned professors, lecturers,
>   teachers, and a few students, nearly
>   eighty in all, totted up their columns
>   of figures and drew their
>   periodographs, and were quite elated
>   when their totals came out right.

Finally, although it's about copyists rather than computers, I can't resist citing a little excerpt on ergonomics, from Herman Melville's "Bartleby the Scrivener":

> Though of a very ingenious mechanical
>   turn, Nippers could never get this
>   table to suit him. He put chips under
>   it, blocks of various sorts, bits of
>   pasteboard, and at last went so far as
>   to attempt an exquisite adjustment by
>   final pieces of folded blotting-paper.
>   But no invention would answer. If, for
>   the sake of easing his back, he
>   brought the table lid at a sharp angle
>   well up towards his chin, and wrote
>   there like a man using the steep roof
>   of a Dutch house for his desk:—then he
>   declared that it stopped the
>   circulation in his arms. If now he
>   lowered the table to his waistbands,
>   and stooped over it in writing, then
>   there was a sore aching in his back.
>   In short, the truth of the matter was,
>   Nippers knew not what he wanted. Or,
>   if he wanted any thing, it was to be
>   rid of a scrivener’s table altogether.